# How to convert to blob a pdf file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I have a pdf file path from the backend, something like:`http://example.com.com:3000/Invoices/11117_131805449_Invoice.pdf`...
and, I want to download it on button click.

On the frontend I have done:

```
 const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob([invoicePath], { type: "application/pdf" })
      );
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute("download", `invoice_${id}.pdf`);
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
```

and, when I click to download it, it is downloaded, but show an error like: "Failed to load PDF document"...
Any idea?

Comment: If you do it in react, can't you just do `<a href={invoicePath} download={\`invoice_${id}\`} class="button">Button content</a>`? Instead of having a `button` element?

Comment: @ShamPooSham yes, I'm using react. Also the code is doing almost the same... I just tried your suggestion, but it opens a new window. I want to download the pdf.

Comment: Yes, it does almost the same thing, but generally it's not as good to manipulate the DOM manually when using react. The `download` attribute should make so that the PDF gets downloaded, did you make sure to include that?

Comment: yes, ```download``` is included and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a Blob URL using the invoicePath, however, this approach will not work because creating a Blob URL does not actually download the file from the server.

To download the file, you need to make a request to the server to get the PDF file and then create a Blob URL from the response data. Here's an updated version of your code that should work:

```
fetch(invoicePath)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute("download", `invoice_${id}.pdf`);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: tried something like this, but got some cors errors. maybe some backend stuff now. thank u.